# How to dynamically locate jjs.exe on Windows machines?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, nashorn

I'm trying to run Nashorn on a Windows machine and would like to provide a simple `start.bat` file to start it.

On Unix-derivatives that is very easy; but on Windows, I struggle to reliably find the location of jjs.exe.

I don't want to tell my users: Oh, go find the location of the Java 8 SDK and edit `start.bat` to point it to that directory.

I tried:

> $ where java
>
> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

Which doesn't contain jjs.exe either.
`JAVA_HOME` or `JDK_HOME` isn't set by default, and the bin directory isn't in PATH either; so now it seems I have to rely on guessing default locations.

Are there any other options?

Comment: It is dead-simple on Unix-derivates because someone set the PATH, so a simple `$ jjs` will start the (first found) program. AFAIK if you do a standard Java installation on Windows the PATH is set too by the installation procedure.

Comment: Probably you can find with `where /r %SystemDrive%\ jjs.exe`.

Comment: Windows depending on version will have all kinds of ideas of where Java is located. Also, if you install the 32-bit vs 64-bit version, you are looking at different paths. And to make matters worse, you can actually chose the location of the JDK in the installer

Comment: Also, your solution gives me several paths and implies the JDK was installed on %SystemDrive%

Comment: It gives you several paths because you have installed the JDK (and maybe diferent Java versions). If user has only JRE installed you should got only one path. I don't say it is simple, but it can be done when you know well the Windows shell (sorry, not my case).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think *anything* is going to be **absolutely** foolproof here, as there are a huge number of ways to potentially install Java (ZIP an installation on one machine and put it on another, for example). You don't tell us how your users are installing, or how you can even be sure they have Java 8 (which is required for `jjs`).

But probably good enough is to assume the user actually ran the installer. In that case, you can find Java information in the registry. See `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.8\JavaHome`, which should give you the Java home directory of the most recent 1.8 installation (you can also look for specific releases under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.8.0_*`).

So, for example, on my test machine:

```
C:\Users\IEUser>reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.8" /v JavaHome

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.8
    JavaHome    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
```

Comment: I'm assuming users have installed a Java 8 JDK, yes.

Comment: If you know it's a JDK the search under that registry key is more straightforward, then. I'll update the answer.

Comment: alright, I'll try this. Thanks! Should allow me to get rid of running FindJJS

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution but I'm not sure how good it is.
It assumes a JDK has been installed.

```
import java.io.File;

public class FindJJS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "jjs" + (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows") ? ".exe" : ""));
    }
}
```

Compile it, put it in lib/

In start.bat:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`java -cp lib FindJJS`) do "%%a"-scripting bin\yourscript.jjs -- %1
```